# Моделирование движения небесных тел (Проблема N тел)

Tags: c++, opengl

Здравствуйте. Я пытаюсь запрограммировать движение планет солнечной системы вокруг солнца (задача n-тел). Но столкнулся с проблемой - Планеты летают во круг солнца(у меня оно непоздвижная точка) так как вроде-бы должны, но как только я добавляю луну, то она не кружится вокруг Земли, а так же кружится вокруг солнца. Если же делаю взаимодействие всех тел между собой, тогда у меня они разлетаются. Подскажите пожалуйста, где я мог ошибиться.

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "GL/glut.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include "cmath"
using namespace std;

double MassSun = 1.99*pow(10, 30);
double MassEarth = 5.98*pow(10, 24);
double MassMoon = 7.32*pow(10, 22);
double EccentrisityEarth = 0.01671022;
double AstroUnit =1;
double LunarDistance =1.00257;
const int N =8;

struct Particle
{
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
    double vx;
    double vy;
    double vz;
    double m;
    double ax;
    double ay;
    double az;
    vector<double>tx, ty,tz;

};
Particle p[N];
double dt = 0.001;
double c = 0;
int t = 1;
void display()
{

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glPointSize(1);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    int scale =250;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {   
        if (i == 0)
            glColor3d(1, 0, 0);
        if (i == 1)
            glColor3d(0, 1, 0);
        if (i == 2)
            glColor3d(1, 1, 1);
        if (i == 3)
            glColor3d(1, 1, 0);     
        if (i == 4)
            glColor3d(1, 0, 1);
        if (i == 5)
            glColor3d(0,1, 1);
        if (i == 6)
            glColor3d(0.5, 0, 0);
        if (i == 7)
            glColor3d(0, 0.5, 0);
        if (i == 8)
            glColor3d(0, 0, 0.5);
        if (i == 9)
            glColor3d(0.5, 0.5, 0.);

        for (int j = 0; j<p[i].tx.size(); j++)
            glVertex3d( p[i].tx[j] * scale,  p[i].ty[j]* scale,p[i].tz[j]*scale);
        cout << p[2].x << " " << p[2].y << endl;
    }
    glEnd();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
double Gr;
double k = 0;
void timer(int = 0)
{

    Gr = (4 * M_PI*M_PI);
    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
    {
        p[i].ax = p[i].ay = p[i].az = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            if (i != j)
            {
                double r = pow((pow(p[i].x - p[j].x, 2.0) + pow(p[i].y - p[j].y, 2.0) + pow(p[i].z - p[j].z, 2.0)), 3.0 / 2.0);

                    p[i].ax += -Gr*p[j].m*(p[i].x - p[j].x) / (r*p[0].m);
                    p[i].ay += -Gr*p[j].m*(p[i].y - p[j].y) / (r*p[0].m);
                    p[i].az += -Gr*p[j].m*(p[i].z - p[j].z) / (r*p[0].m);
            }
    }

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    p[i].vx = p[i].vx + dt*p[i].ax;
    p[i].vy = p[i].vy + dt*p[i].ay;
    p[i].vz = p[i].vz + dt*p[i].az;
    p[i].x = p[i].x + dt*p[i].vx;
    p[i].y = p[i].y + dt*p[i].vy;
    p[i].z = p[i].z + dt*p[i].vz;
    p[i].tx.push_back(p[i].x);
    p[i].ty.push_back(p[i].y);
    p[i].tz.push_back(p[i].z);
}
    display();

    glutTimerFunc(1, timer, 0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

/*p[0].x = 0;
p[0].y = 0;
p[0].z = 0;
p[0].vx = 0;
p[0].vy = 0;
p[0].vz = 0;
p[0].m = MassSun;
p[0].ax = 0;
p[0].ay = 0;
p[0].az = 0;

p[1].x = AstroUnit;
p[1].y = 0;
p[1].z = 0;
p[1].vx = 0;
p[1].vy = 2 * M_PI*AstroUnit;
p[1].vz = 0;
p[1].m = MassEarth;
p[1].ax = 0;
p[1].ay = 0;
p[1].az = 0;

p[2].x = LunarDistance;
p[2].y = 0;
p[2].z = 0;
p[2].vx = 0;
p[2].vy = 2 * M_PI*LunarDistance;
p[2].vz = 0;
p[2].m = 0.073483e24;
p[2].ax = 0;
p[2].ay = 0;
p[2].az = 0;
*/
    p[0].x = 0;
    p[0].y = 0;
    p[0].z = 0;
    p[0].vx = 0;
    p[0].vy =0;
    p[0].vz = 00;
    p[0].m = MassSun ;
    p[0].ax = 0;
    p[0].ay = 0;
    p[0].az = 0;

p[1].x = 0.38710;
p[1].y = 0;
p[1].z = 0;
p[1].vx = 0;
p[1].vy =2*M_PI* 0.38710/ 0.24085;
p[1].vz = 0;
p[1].m = 0.33022e24;
p[1].ax = 0;
p[1].ay = 0;
p[1].az = 0;

p[2].x = 0.72333;
p[2].y = 0;
p[2].z = 0;
p[2].vx = 0;
p[2].vy = 2*M_PI*0.72333/0.61521;
p[2].vz = 0;
p[2].m = 4.8690e24;
p[2].ax = 0;
p[2].ay = 0;
p[2].az = 0;

p[3].x = AstroUnit;
p[3].y = 0;
p[3].z = 0;
p[3].vx = 0;
p[3].vy = 2 * M_PI*AstroUnit;
p[3].vz = 0;
p[3].m = MassEarth;
p[3].ax = 0;
p[3].ay = 0;
p[3].az = 0;

p[4].x = 1.52363;
p[4].y = 0;
p[4].z = 0;
p[4].vx = 0;
p[4].vy =2*M_PI* 1.52363/1.88078;
p[4].vz = 0;
p[4].m = 0.64191e24;
p[4].ax = 0;
p[4].ay = 0;
p[4].az = 0;

p[5].x = 5.20441;
p[5].y = 0;
p[5].z = 0;
p[5].vx = 0;
p[5].vy = 2*M_PI* 5.20441/11.8677;
p[5].vz = 0;
p[5].m = 1898.8e24;
p[5].ax = 0;
p[5].ay = 0;
p[5].az = 0;

p[6].x = 9.58378;
p[6].y = 0;
p[6].z = 0;
p[6].vx = 0;
p[6].vy =2*M_PI*9.58378/29.6661;
p[6].vz = 0;
p[6].m = 568.50e24;
p[6].ax = 0;
p[6].ay = 0;
p[6].az = 0;

p[7].x = 19.18722;
p[7].y = 0;
p[7].z = 0;
p[7].vx = 0;
p[7].vy = 2 * M_PI*19.18722 / 84.048;
p[7].vz = 0;
p[7].m = 86.625e24;
p[7].ax = 0;
p[7].ay = 0;
p[7].az = 0;

p[8].x = 30.02090;
p[8].y = 0;
p[8].z = 0;
p[8].vx = 0;
p[8].vy = 2 * M_PI*30.02090 / 164.491;
p[8].vz = 0;
p[8].m = 102.78;
p[8].ax = 0;
p[8].ay = 0;
p[8].az = 0;


p[9].x = 39.23107;
p[9].y = 0;
p[9].z = 0;
p[9].vx = 0;
p[9].vy = 2 * M_PI*39.23107 / 245.73;
p[9].vz = 0;
p[9].m = 0.015;
p[9].ax = 0;
p[9].ay = 0;
p[9].az = 0;

glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
glutCreateWindow("Avada Kedabra");
glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);;
glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(-10000,10000, -10000, 10000, -4000, 4000);
glutDisplayFunc(display);
timer(0);
glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: Уточните, в чем проблема, в расчетах, или в отрисовке? И согласно этому уберите из вопроса лишний код и метку.

Comment: Судя по описанию, проблема в расчётах. Может, у вас недостаточно массивная планета?

Comment: @VladD та вроде не должно же, если летает вокруг солнца нормально (о формулах), а вот планеты крутить не вариант, так как задача то стоит - реальные веса использовать

Comment: Ну, если напутать в массах и расстояниях друг от друга, то будет летать не туда. Или начальная скорость может быть не та.

Comment: `Gr` -- это гравитационная постоянная? Странное какое-то значение...

Comment: @avp Да, я то в физике не силен, подходил к знакомому преподавателю физики, он подсказал как и что можно изменить что бы они летали, они то начали летать с такими параметрами, но добавляя спутники, оно все не действует

Comment: связанный вопрос: [python3 recursion animation in QuickDraw](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13520435/4279) (в частности, [полный пример кода](https://gist.github.com/a011754fa77737e099b7#file_main.py))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так...

- 1 шаг)Отрисовать все планеты с "центром мира" в солнце.
- 2 шаг)Сместить планеты относительно солнца (если нужно)
- 3 шаг)Перенести "ценр мира" в землю отрисовать луну относительно
  земли.

Весь секрет в смещение относительно объекта.

Comment: Попытки были. Я даже привязывал отдельно луну к земле, потом подключал солнце, оно либо разлетается либо крутится вокруг солнца. 
Я уже даже голову сломал чего уже так может быть

Comment: Работоспособность программы, моделирующей поведение таких тел, не может никак зависеть от выбора "центра мира". Поэтому не ясно, о каком "секрете" вы ведете речь.

Comment: @AnT Тогда получается, скорее всего проблема в коде, если так рассуждать?

Answer (score 0):

Я бы еще нормировал задачу, приведя физические величины во вменяемые безразмерные (не всякие 25-е степени). И постарался бы задать корректные начальные условия.

Comment: Я пробовал, но задача таки поставлена в том что бы использовать реальные массы. Получается у меня так, что если я отдельно рассматриваю солнце-землю, землю-луну, то они хорошо таки двигаются и луна крутится вокруг земли, но как только добавляю влияние солнца(во второй случай) оно возращается восвоясе. Т.е. опять луна стает "планетой". а если связать все со всеми, то разлетается.

Comment: Значит шаг надо уменьшить. Или попробовать хотя бы движение Луны  считать с другим (меньшим) шагом. А в начальном расстоянии до Луны Вы уверены? (1 а.е. примерно 150000000км т.е. у Вас до Луны 150188550 или всего 188550км за Землей, а на самом деле от Л до З д.б. около 380000км)

Comment: @avp  Оу, прощу прощения, там была опечатка, единица лишняя(поправил), хотя расчеты веду с 1.00257. А вот на тему шага попробую сейчас.